Поиск записи по колонке с массивом
Мне нужно реализовать вывод записей из БД при выборе нескольких категорий.
При выборе чекбоксов с нужными категориями я, при помощи Ajax, передаю в бэк массив с ID выбранных категорий. Данные выглядят так: ['1', '2'].
В БД у каждой записи есть колонка category_ids в которой указаны категории по которым их можно найти. Хранятся так: ["1", "2", "3"].
Но столкнулся с тем, что проект использует библиотеку fluentPDO и как реализовать выборку не пойму.
Пожалуйста, если не знаете ответа, как решить, то и не пишите, какой fluentPDO плохой и что надо использовать что-то поновее и моднее или по типу "ну подумай сам". Понятно, вы тут самые умные, крутые, а я тупой. Не будем тратить время на пустые бла-бла.


public function getByProjectsAjax($data = '')
    {
        $query = DB::db()->from(Projects::getTable())
            if (!empty($data['categoryFilter'])) {
                $query->where('category_ids = ?', array(json_encode($data['categoryFilter']));
            }
            $query->orderBy('id DESC')
            ->fetchAll();
        return $query;
    }




Это называется плохой дизайн БД. Связь многие-ко-многим реализуется через третью таблицу, а не через джсоновые костыли.

Присоединяюсь к u_murder. Наглядный пример: у некоторой записи в category_ids записано '1,2,3', а в фильтре, по которому делаем выборку - [1,3].

Как вариант попробуй использовать SELECT IN.
Должно всё выглядеть следующим образом:
// Значения для условия IN
$values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// Построение запроса SELECT с условием IN
$query->where('category_ids IN ?', $values);


пробовал, но ошибку выдает:  Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

@Aquila попробуй так, $query->where('category_ids IN (:values)', [':values' => $values]);

тоже самое пишет. Если бы в бд у записи категория была бы одна, то проще было бы и всё работало. Но с массивом беда.

Рашение нашел грубоватое, но если есть у кого идеи, как сделать лучшее...


if (!empty($data['categoryFilter'])) {
  $string_version = implode(',', $data['categoryFilter']);
  $ids = '';
                
  foreach ($data['categoryFilter'] as $key => $item) {
    $ids .= ' OR JSON_CONTAINS(projects.category_ids, "[\"'.$item.'\"]")';
  }
                
  $query->where(
    'JSON_CONTAINS(projects.category_ids, "[\"'.$string_version.'\"]") '.$ids.'',
  );
}




Хана производительности. Это движку нужно будет при любом запросе просматривать все записи. Никакая индексация работать не будет.

Вам уже сказали, как сделать лучше
